# React.js updates some part of DOM nodes when I'm deleting only one element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As I know React creates a new Virtual DOM and compares it with previous one, then it updates Browser DOM with least number of changes possible without rendering the entire DOM again. (in short)

In React documentation I have also read how [**key**](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) should work.

for demonstrating this, I have created todo app, but when I'm deleting one element, all previous elements are re-rendered again (except if I'm not deleting recently added element)

Here is screenshot:

[image]

(In Chrome developer tool **paint flashing** is active for showing renders)

My questions:

1. Why do previous elements re-render again?
2. Why [**key**](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) could not fix this problem?

Here is the entire code:

TodoApp.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Input from './Input';
import List from './List';

const TodoApp = () => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const onSubmitChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setTodos([
      ...todos,
      { text: inputText, completed: false, id: Math.random() * 1000 },
    ]);
    setInputText('');
  };

  const onChangeEvent = e => {
    setInputText(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {todos.map(todo => {
        return (
          <List todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} todo={todo} key={todo.id} />
        );
      })}
      <Input
        onSubmit={onSubmitChange}
        onChange={onChangeEvent}
        inputText={inputText}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoApp;
```

List.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import "../todolist/css/TodoApp.css"

const List = ({ todo, todos, setTodos }) => {
  const deleteHandle = () => {
    setTodos(todos.filter(el => el.id !== todo.id));
  };

  const completeHandle = () => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map(el => {
        if (el.id === todo.id) {
          return { ...el, completed: !el.completed };
        }
        return el;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className={`${todo.completed ? 'completed' : ''}`}>
      <div>{todo.text}</div>
      <div className="btns">
        <button onClick={deleteHandle} className="btn btn-delete">
          Delete
        </button>
        <button onClick={completeHandle} className="btn btn-complete">
          complete
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Input.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

const Input = ({ onSubmit, onChange, inputText }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input
        onChange={onChange}
        value={inputText}
        type="text"
        name="myInput"
        autoComplete="off"
      />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Comment: You don't memoize anything, on state change they will rerender

Comment: @DennisVash what do you mean?

Comment: Use React.memo, then they won't re-render as the parent component won't be looking for state changes. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Comment: But even with `memo` as you are passing all `todos` to each item, they will all rerender each time `todos` is changed

Comment: But why do we need to use memorization? Then what Reconciliation do? As I know diffing algorithm compares old and new virtual trees, then if something is changed it renders only updated element into Browser DOM not entire elements. Maybe I don't understand this process properly. @dbuchet

Comment: Component is render which means its virtual dom will be compared to dom (and yes maybe fom will not change but comparison is performed) memoization prevent to perform this comparison as we're sure this component should not rerender

Comment: Why `key` could not fix this problem? @dbuchet

Comment: Last question: as you have mentioned even with `memo` as I'm passing all `todos` to each item, they will all re-render each time `todos` is changed. then how can I solve problem? @dbuchet

Comment: If you need to pass `todos` to all your items, unfortunately you have no solution. One solution should be to have `completeHandle` and `deleteHandle` in your `TodoApp` instead of `List`. So you won't need `todos` in `List`. For your first question, `key` is just used to keep track of components across renders, and their inner states